# Reset iPhone App - applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: iphone

I'm looking to reset my application completely when it becomes inactive.

I dont want any states retained, is there an easy way to do this?

Would this be done in the Background Method? or any other of the State Methods within the application delegate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest disabling iOS 4 backgrounding by adding the key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to your info.plist

Comment: If this solved your question, you should mark it as "the solution" by clicking the checkmark next to my answer.